set targetSdk for androidTest apk
By default, the targetSdk of the test apk generated to run androidTest on a library is the minSdk.
Is there a way to explicitly set the targetSdk for the generated androidTest.apk to something different than the minSdk ?

The targetSdk can be set in testOptions block:
android {
    testOptions {
        targetSdk = 34
    }
}

